# Image transformation

Tags: image-processing

I have to images ([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl6tD.png), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5dFi.png)) which should be overlapped.

The best solution which I find is the following:

```
{merit, trans} = FindGeometricTransform[img2, img1, TransformationClass -> "Similarity"]

imgt = ImageTransformation[img2, trans, DataRange -> Full];

overlapped = Blend[{ColorNegate[img1], imgt}, {0.5, 0.5}]    

ImageAssemble[{img1, img2, overlapped}]
```

[image]

**In the lower part** of the overlapped image a small **vertical misalignment of the horizontal lines** is seen.

**How can the adjustment be optimized/improved?**

Comment: Try adding Method -> {"ImageAlign", {"Keypoints", "BRISK"}} or some other variant of Keypoints related methods, like "AKAZE" or "KAZE" or "ORB"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica 11.1 introduces keypoints-based registration methods. As your example exhbits patterns with relatively large homogeneous regions, a global intensity difference based target function might lead to suboptimal results as in your attempt. Try using keypoints, e.g. [binary robust invariant scalable keypoints (BRISK)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.371.1343&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

```
img1 = Import@"https://i.imgur.com/RJEFiuO.png";
img2 = Import@"https://i.imgur.com/J79TrG9.png";
{merit, trans} = FindGeometricTransform[img2, img1, 
  Method -> {"ImageAlign", {"Keypoints", "BRISK"}}, 
  TransformationClass -> "Similarity"];
imgt = ImageTransformation[img2, trans, DataRange -> Full];
overlapped = Blend[{ColorNegate[img1], imgt}, {0.5, 0.5}];
ImageAssemble[{img1, img2, imgt, overlapped}]
```

[image: assembled resulting images]

You might want to see the locations of the corresponding keypoints used inside `FindGeometricTransform` (demonstrated using code given in the Neat Examples section of `ImageCorrespondingPoints`):

```
matches = ImageCorrespondingPoints[img1, img2, Method -> "BRISK", 
 TransformationClass -> "Similarity"];
ImageAssemble[{MapThread[Show[#1, Graphics[{Yellow, 
 MapIndexed[Inset[#2[[1]], #1] & , #2]}]] &, {{img1, img2}, matches}]}]
```

[image]